# Excel show percentage of specific status in pivot chart

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2007

I have a table with requests to our professionals, and each **request** has an status that's either **open** or **closed** and the name of the person **responsible** for it

What I'm trying to achieve is to show in a pivot table/chart, for each **responsible**, show the percentage of their **requests** which have the status set to **open**

My problem is that I managed to show the percentage of total, or column, but I want the percentage of that **responsible** only

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I already have the pivot table, and created several graphs, but this particular one I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Make responsible your row label

Comment: @Xogle but what I put in values? % of total or column doesn't work

Comment: The count of status and then get the percent out of that

Comment: @Xogle thanks, it's working but it shows both closed and open requests, but if I filter to only show open, they all go to 100%, can I somehow just hide the ones with closed status?

Comment: For the easiest solution, why don't you just hide the column?

Answer (score 0):

This is using Excel 2013 but I think is in principle the same for Excel 2007.

Assuming data such as in A1:C11, a PivotTable might be created as shown:

[image: SO44934759 example]

The right hand column (`% OPEN`) of which is a Calculated Item with formula:

```
=OPEN/(Closed+OPEN)
```

Then filtering Column Labels to select only that column and inserting a column chart of the PivotTable should lead to a chart similar to that shown.